# add API permissions to application Azure AD with PATCH graph.microsoft.com API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azureportal

I am trying to add API permissions to my application via the patch method.

I have 4 permissions i am trying to add.

```
$appPermissionsRequired = @('RoleManagement.ReadWrite.Directory', 'PrivilegedAccess.ReadWrite.AzureADGroup', 'Group.read.all', 'Directory.read.all')
```

I have another method there finds the correct id for the permission and then put it in the list "roleassignments"

```
$RoleAssignments = @()
Foreach ($AppPermission in $appPermissionsRequired) {

    $RoleAssignment = $targetSp.AppRoles | Where-Object { $_.value -eq $AppPermission }

    $RoleAssignments += $RoleAssignment

}
```

the problem is that when i run the patch method it gives me a: "code":"Request_BadRequest

the whole error message:

```
WARNING: {"error":{"code":"Request_BadRequest","message":"Specified HTTP method is not allowed for the request target.","innerError":{"date":"2021-11-03T07:37:41","request-id":"28769332-907b-47dc-bc98-f45754e17226","client-request-id":"28769332-907b-47dc-bc98-f45754e17226"}}}
```

```html
 foreach ($RoleAssignment in $RoleAssignments) {
            $restSplat = @{
                Method  = "PATCH"
                uri     = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications?`$filter=appId eq '$appId'"
                headers = @{"Authorization" = "Bearer $AADToken"; "Content-Type" = "application/json"}
                body    = @{ 
                    requiredResourceAccess = @(
                        @{
                            resourceAppId  = $targetSp.appId
                            resourceAccess = @(
                                @{
                                    id   = $RoleAssignment.Id
                                    type = "Role"
                                }
                            )
                        }    
                    )
                } | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 4
            } 
            $restSplat
            $rest = (Invoke-RestMethod @restSplat).Value
        }
```

Comment: Check the URL in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http. You can't use the base /applications endpoint for the update.

Comment: i dont understand, why can't i do that? and can i do it in another way then?

Comment: You need to use the URL in the docs: /applications/<app object id>. You can get the objectId from the application object.

Comment: So now i get a   `{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_BadRequest",
        "message": "Specified HTTP method is not allowed for the request target.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-11-03T10:20:42",
            "request-id": "bd70d05e-2be5-4a2a-93e6-970d9bff2bf6",
            "client-request-id": "89150a2f-14eb-9a32-3bd6-725307c4fb37"
        }
    }
}`

Comment: and: Method Not Allowed - 405 - 151m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications` which does not have a `PATCH` operation because it used for List: `GET /applications` and Create: `POST /applications`.

To update `requiredResourceAccess` for an application using `PATCH` operation you need to call `PATCH /applications/{directoryObjectId}`. Note that `directoryObjectId` is not the appId but the object Id of the application on Azure portal or from `Get /applications`

Instead of

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications?`$filter=appId eq '$appId'
```

Use

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/object-id
```

Remember that this operation will neither add admin consent on the permissions and it will replace the property so run a one off request.